# how to redirect to a division(<div>) using javascript function in my html page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cordova

My problem is that I want to redirect within my same html page which contain a div named `add-form`.

When I click on the `button` my redirection should be on one `div` which contains some code.
Here is some of my code that redirects to another page, but I have no idea how to replace the page with a `div` instead.

```
 success: function(data){

          if(data['success']){
        alert("DOne");  

        window.location = document.getElementById('add-form');
         // $("#add-form").load(function(e) {

         // });


          }
          else{
              alert("Oops, There is a Network Error.....");
          }
      }
```

In this code `#add-form` is `DIV id`.

I don't want to redirect to another page but to slide in the page that contain `div tag`.

**UPDATE:**

here are the two images.

[image: First Image]

In the first image click of **+** button which held in right side up.
code is :

```
<a href="#add-form" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
```

result is this image.

[image: second Image]

I want to do the same for a button click, but in javascript.

Comment: Do you just want the browser to scroll to the Div when the user clicks a link?

Comment: $("#add-form").get(0).scrollIntoView(); => this should work for you

Comment: Why do you need to do it in JS? Why not just <a href="#add-form">Click</a>

Comment: @TalhaMasood @ScottHelme I need to open slide panel when condition is satisfied in a onclick event and the slide panel is a `<DIV>`.

Comment: Then that means you need to animate a div visible if the condition is satisfied. Keep the div hidden by default, and make it visible by animation if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: @TalhaMasood 
 see my **UPDATE**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is this:

```
<a href="#add-form">Click</a>
```

When a user clicks that link, they will be scrolled to the div with `id="add-form"`.

*Edit*

I can't test right now, but try something like this to do it in JS:

```
$("#buttonToClick").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#add-form").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: i want to do it inside the JS function.

Comment: I've updated it some JS to scroll to the div when an element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you really **must** do it in JS (although, I cannot see why you wouldn't use Scott Helme's solution), use this line to anchor your browser to the position of the div with the id "add-form":

> window.location.href = '#add-form';

Make sure to prepend the hash (**#**) to the element's ID.

Comment: I have tried in my phone but it shows `file not found exception.`

Comment: Is the div (I assume that's what you mean by 'panel') visible by default and you just want to position the browser to the location of the div? Or is the div hidden, and you want the code to **show the div AND** position you to its location?